# Link de ajuda das filas de análise não deveria abrir na mesma aba/janela

Tags: novo-recurso, filas-de-análise

Hoje entrei nas filas de análise e me surpreendi com esse novo layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficou bem melhor e limpo, e não precisa por exemplo abrir as perguntas em nova aba para olhar mais em detalhes.

Só que o link "*Learn more*" está abrindo na mesma aba, então se eu clico nele, depois tenho que voltar para a página da fila.
Este link não poderia abrir como um popup na própria página ou em outra página (aba)?

Comment: No meu entendimento, abrir em separado ou na mesma aba deve ser uma escolha do leitor. Num link normal (como é o caso), se um usuário preferir uma nova aba, um clique com botão do meio ou control click abre em separado na maioria dos navegadores. Se você força um target _blank, eliminou a escolha, o link vai sempre abrir uma aba/janela nova mesmo que o usuário não queira. Em geral, forçar abas separadas deveria ser só para conteúdo externo, e mesmo assim, com muitas ressalvas.

Comment: por isso um popup seria melhor, antes quando tinha duvida abria um link abaixo dos votos, isso era bem funciona, seria a mesma coisa, não precisa ser uma nova aba